# how to move edittext or imageview in only that particular relative layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, touch-event, ontouchlistener, motionevent

```
    public class MyActivity extends Activity implements View.OnTouchListener {

    TextView _view;
    ViewGroup _root;
    private int _xDelta;
    private int _yDelta;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        _root = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.root);

        _view = new TextView(this);
        _view.setText("TextView!!!!!!!!");

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(150, 50);
        layoutParams.leftMargin = 50;
        layoutParams.topMargin = 50;
        layoutParams.bottomMargin = -250;
        layoutParams.rightMargin = -250;
        _view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

        _view.setOnTouchListener(this);
        _root.addView(_view);
    }

    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        final int X = (int) event.getRawX();
        final int Y = (int) event.getRawY();
        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
                _xDelta = X - lParams.leftMargin;
                _yDelta = Y - lParams.topMargin;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
                layoutParams.leftMargin = X - _xDelta;
                layoutParams.topMargin = Y - _yDelta;
                layoutParams.rightMargin = -250;
                layoutParams.bottomMargin = -250;
                view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                break;
        }
        _root.invalidate();
        return true;
    }}
```

**I have doing this code for moving edittext and imageview.It's moving fine but it moves also outside the relative layout.I have to put restriction for moving only in particular layout.Anyone have suggestion?**

Comment: Try using the Absolute layout.

Comment: @GrIsHu, I try absolute layout but it not set margin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out Drag & Drop Functionality Code below which i have implemented:

**DragAndDrop.java**

```
  public class DragAndDrop extends Activity
   {
private ImageView m_ivImage, m_ivImage1;
private int m_counter = 0;
float m_lastTouchX, m_lastTouchY, m_posX, m_posY, m_prevX, m_prevY, m_imgXB, m_imgYB, m_imgXC, m_imgYC, m_dx, m_dy;
private LinearLayout m_llTop;
private AbsoluteLayout m_alTop;
private Button m_btnAddView, m_btnRemove;
private Context m_context;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    m_context = this;

    m_prevX = 0;
    m_prevY = 0;
    m_imgXB = 50;
    m_imgYB = 100;
    m_imgXC = 150;
    m_imgYC = 100;

    m_ivImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivImage);
    m_ivImage1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivImage1);
    m_llTop = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llTop);
    m_alTop = (AbsoluteLayout) findViewById(R.id.alTop);
    m_btnAddView = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
    m_btnRemove = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRemove);

    m_ivImage.setOnTouchListener(m_onTouchListener);
    m_ivImage1.setOnTouchListener(m_onTouchListener);
    m_btnAddView.setOnClickListener(m_onClickListener);
    m_btnRemove.setOnClickListener(m_onClickListener);

}

/**
 * Common click listener for clickable controls
 */
OnClickListener m_onClickListener = new OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View p_v)
    {
        switch (p_v.getId())
            {
                case R.id.btnAdd:
                    addView();
                    break;
                case R.id.btnRemove:
                    removeView();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
    }
};

/**
 * Touch listener for view
 */
OnTouchListener m_onTouchListener = new OnTouchListener(){

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View p_v, MotionEvent p_event)
    {
        switch (p_event.getAction())
            {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                {
                    m_lastTouchX = p_event.getX();
                    m_lastTouchY = p_event.getY();
                    break;
                }
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                {
                    break;
                }

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                {
                    m_dx = p_event.getX() - m_lastTouchX;
                    m_dy = p_event.getY() - m_lastTouchY;

                    m_posX = m_prevX + m_dx;
                    m_posY = m_prevY + m_dy;

                    if (m_posX > 0 && m_posY > 0 && (m_posX + p_v.getWidth()) < m_alTop.getWidth() && (m_posY + p_v.getHeight()) < m_alTop.getHeight())
                    {
                        p_v.setLayoutParams(new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(p_v.getMeasuredWidth(), p_v.getMeasuredHeight(), (int) m_posX, (int) m_posY));

                        m_prevX = m_posX;
                        m_prevY = m_posY;

                    }

                    break;

                }

            }
        return true;
    }
};

/**
 * Add view dynamically for drag and drop
 */
private void addView()
{
    ImageView m_img = new ImageView(m_context);
    if (m_counter < 5)
    {
            m_img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            m_alTop.addView(m_tv, new LayoutParams(android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ((int) m_imgXB), ((int) m_imgYB)));
            m_alTop.addView(m_img, new LayoutParams(android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ((int) m_imgXB), ((int) m_imgYB)));

        m_counter++;
        if (m_counter == 5)
            m_btnAddView.setEnabled(false);
    }

    m_img.setOnTouchListener(m_onTouchListener);
    m_tv.setOnTouchListener(m_onTouchListener);
}

public void removeView()
{
    m_counter = 0;
    m_alTop.removeAllViews();
    m_alTop.invalidate();
    m_btnAddView.setEnabled(true);
}
```

**Layout file**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/llTop"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <AbsoluteLayout
        android:id="@+id/alTop"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_weight=".70"
         >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivImage1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_x="193dp"
            android:layout_y="29dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </AbsoluteLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight=".30" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/addview" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnRemove"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/removeview"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: thanks for reply but it's not working for me.when I used absolute layout, that view is not moving.It stay static.I need only layout's current height and width in Action view as like you define in if condition.Is this possible?

Comment: Yes you can get layout's current height and width as i have defined and restrict it in my code. You may have missed the view's touch listener to move it.

Comment: No..I cant restrict it in only LinearLayout.And second problem is When I moving latest edittext or imageview, it also moving oldest edittext or imageview.I added you in Google+.Any solution for this?

Comment: Have you tried with my code ? It works perfect. Just try with my code.

Comment: ok..apart from this problem.Can we store height,width,xaxis and yaxis of layout and inner layouts?

Comment: Yes you can store it. But its bit complicated to take each view's height,width,xaxis,yaxis etc.. and store it and manage it.

Comment: Actually I stored height,width,xaxis and yaxis of layout and as per this data layout will displayed.Is  this possible?

Comment: How can i get layout's position like as header or footer?

Comment: @GrlsHu, thanks for replied..I got it.I make layout from database.

Comment: Glad to help. Vote the answer if it helped you. :)

Comment: @GrlsHu, Can i chat with you on Google+? I need more help.

Comment: Are you online on Google+?

Comment: Yes... what is your id ?

Comment: Hi @GrlsHu, can u know how to reload current activity?